# `Popover` of Ant-Design causes jagging when `content` is big enough, how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I use [`Popover`](https://ant.design/components/popover/).

When I hover on the `Hover me` button, it displays an image.

I know because the height of the image is too long, longer than the window height + `overflow: auto`, it creates a scrollbar on the right. But why didn't it display the scrollbar once and smoothly, but jagging?

The scrollbar instead of `hide` -> `show` 
It is `hide` -> `show` -> `hide` -> `show` -> `hide` -> `show` (happens within under 100ms)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is interesting and here's what I found. 1) It renders the popover upon hover. 2) After rendering the popover, it applies the shadow on the bottom border. The jagged behavior is due to step 2. Here's what I encourage you to do. After your sandbox loads, hover over the button and stay hovered. After the image loads, scroll to the bottom of the window. You'll see that the shadow isn't rendered during this initial hover. Now unhover, hover again, and scroll to the bottom of the window. See that extra shadow? The scrollbar had to "readjust" for that extra bottom shadow.

Comment: Also, during the initial hover, you won't notice the jagged behavior. It is only in subsequent hovers, that the scrollbar behaves this way. That is why I believe the bottom shadow to be the culprit.

Comment: Great finding, but no solution tho? I tried adding `autoAdjustOverflow={false} placement="bottomLeft"` and the jagging behavior becoming unexpected.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple solution. You'd have to modify the source code of the component, or report this behavior on their github as a bug.